# Is Apache Prefork working fast then Worker MPM to serve static content?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mpm-prefork, mpm-worker, ab

I have found so many stuff related to Apache worker MPM is working fast than Prefork MPM, i know nginx is another option but i want to stick on apache as for use of htaccess and some other features, so i am doing a comparison using apache benchmark testing to serve static content (bg.png) file (size=232KB) and i surprised to see results that apache prefork serving static content faster than worker, the difference is not so big, but the results put me in doubt and i am not taking a decision on below tests, so please guide and help me.

Both tests are done on same server using loopback interface (127.0.0.1) localhost to avoid doubts related to network / bandwidth delays and also without keep alive.

**1) Test using apache prefork**

## prefork MPM

StartServers       5
MinSpareServers    3
MaxSpareServers    5
ServerLimit       256
MaxClients         256
MaxRequestsPerChild 4000

ab -n 1000 -c 900 http://localhost/bg.png

Document Path:          /bg.png
Document Length:        235354 bytes

Concurrency Level:      900
Time taken for tests:   1.053 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      235983024 bytes
HTML transferred:       235738292 bytes
Requests per second:    949.68 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       947.690 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.053 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          218855.25 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0  111 295.5      1    1000
Processing:     3  137 207.8     59     631
Waiting:        0  136 208.1     58     631
Total:         22  248 334.4     73    1024

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     73
  66%     79
  75%    660
  80%    664
  90%    672
  95%   1019
  98%   1022
  99%   1023
 100%   1024 (longest request)

**2) Test using Worker MPM**

ThreadLimit 200
  StartServers 3
  ServerLimit 25
  MaxClients 2000
  MinSpareThreads 50
  MaxSpareThreads 200
  ThreadsPerChild 100
  MaxRequestsPerChild 0

Document Path:          /bg.png
Document Length:        235354 bytes

Concurrency Level:      900
Time taken for tests:   1.061 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      264421004 bytes
HTML transferred:       264146992 bytes
Requests per second:    942.39 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       955.018 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.061 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          243347.56 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   58 158.4     37    1003
Processing:    31  255 330.6     88     884
Waiting:        0  223 336.7     50     870
Total:         68  313 354.1    112    1034

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    112
  66%    150
  75%    900
  80%    905
  90%    920
  95%    921
  98%   1032
  99%   1033
 100%   1034 (longest request)

Below are the differences

**Prefork stats**

Time taken for tests:   **1.053 seconds**
Total transferred:      235983024 bytes
HTML transferred:       235738292 bytes
Requests per second:    949.68 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       **947.690 [ms] (mean)**
Time per request:       **1.053 [ms]** (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          218855.25 [Kbytes/sec] received

worker stats

Time taken for tests:   **1.061 seconds**
Total transferred:      264421004 bytes
HTML transferred:       264146992 bytes
Requests per second:    942.39 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       **955.018 [ms] (mean)**
Time per request:       **1.061 [ms]** (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          243347.56 [Kbytes/sec] received

so as per above stats

**Time taken for tests + Time per request** is less for prefork then worker. So please guide & suggest, is prefork is best for serving static content ??